# Log the error and warning while restoring the sql dump on MySql

Tags: mysql, database, sql, mysqldump

How to log the error and warning while restoring the SQL dump on MySQL ?

Following are the steps we were doing.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE dbname;

mysql> USE dbname;

mysql> SOURCE dbdumpname.sql
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To redirect MySQL errors and warnings to a log file, restore the SQL dump from bash not from a MySQL prompt.

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < dumpfilename.sql > /var/tmp/mysqldump.log 2>&1
```

If you need to supresss foreign key checks, create a shell script named `mysql-import.sh` and put the following contents in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root -p'password' -h hostname db_name << EOF

CREATE DATABASE dbname;
USE dbname;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
SOURCE dbdumpname.sql;

EOF
```

Then `chmod +x mysql-import.sh` to make the script executable and run the script as,

`./mysql-import.sh > /var/log/mysqldump.log 2>&1`

This script will run the code that you were running in MySQL, but with the ability to redirect output to a log file, since it can be invoked from the shell.

Comment: Ok How can I set the foreignkey_checks=0  with the restore command.

Comment: @Arun I am not getting your question.

Comment: While restoring the dump there are possibility of exception due to foreignkey_checks. So we are doing the same as follows.mysql> CREATE DATABASE dbname;

mysql> USE dbname; mysql > set foreign_key_checks=0;

mysql> SOURCE dbdumpname.sql; How can I do this with mysql -u root -p db_name < dumpfilename.sql > /var/tmp/mysqldump.log 2>&1

Comment: @Arun I have updated the answer. Check if it is working.

Answer (score 3):

The mysql client offers a useful `--tee <tofile>` option. Either enable it at startup, or interactively in the prompt.

```
mysql> tee file.log
Logging to file 'file.log'
mysql> \W
Show warnings enabled.
mysql> use database;
mysql> source dump.sql;
```

Note the description in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html#idm140068392103088)

> All the data displayed on the screen is appended into a given file. [..] Tee functionality works only in interactive mode.